# Reduce the dimension of base64 image maintaining aspect ratio in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a base64 string for an image, which i have to display as an icon. If the dimension of an image are bigger i have to display icon maintaining aspect ratio.
I have written a logic to identify if the image is landscape or portrait based on which height and width will be settled for canvas. But seems height and width of icons are not proper as i have hard coded it.

```
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");          
      var height, width;
      if (this.height>this.width) {
            height = 50;
            width = 30;
      } else if (this.height<this.width) {
            height = 30;
            width = 50;
      }
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      ctx.drawImage(image,
            0, 0, this.width, this.height,
            0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height
      );
      var scaledImage = new Image();
      scaledImage.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Is there any way we can calculate it dynamically or any other way to preserve aspect ratio for icons.

Working Example can be found on https://codepen.io/imjaydeep/pen/ewBZRK

[image]

It will be fine if some space will be left on x-y axis.

Comment: of course you can calculate it dynamically but you're not giving enough information.... do you want to scale it by a certain percent? do you have a max width or height you want to scale it to? a max filesize? *how* do you want to scale it?

Comment: If you want to keep aspect ratio and your image doesn't fit the ratio, your image will either leave blanks or be truncated, which one do you want?

Comment: icon size is square say 75*75. if its landscape it takes all width and if its portrait it takes all height. @Iwrestledabearonce.

Comment: @Kaddath remaining area i can keep blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to calculate the scale or ratio and multiply both dimensions by that. Here's an example function, and here's your [edited codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydVaRg).

Creates trimmed, scaled image:

[image]

```
function scaleDataURL(dataURL, maxWidth, maxHeight){
  return new Promise(done=>{
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = ()=>{
      var scale, newWidth, newHeight, canvas, ctx;
      if(img.width < maxWidth){
        scale = maxWidth / img.width;
      }else{
        scale = maxHeight / img.height;
      }
      newWidth = img.width * scale;
      newHeight = img.height * scale;
      canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.height = newHeight;
      canvas.width = newWidth;
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
      done(canvas.toDataURL());
    };
    img.src = dataURL;
  }); 
}
```

Or, if you want the image to always be the provided dimensions with empty surrounding area, you can use this: ([codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewBdKR))

Creates scaled image of exact provided dimensions:

[image]

```
function scaleDataURL(dataURL, maxWidth, maxHeight){
  return new Promise(done=>{
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = ()=>{
      var scale, newWidth, newHeight, canvas, ctx, dx, dy;
      if(img.width < maxWidth){
        scale = maxWidth / img.width;
      }else{
        scale = maxHeight / img.height;
      }
      newWidth = img.width * scale;
      newHeight = img.height * scale;
      canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.height = maxWidth;
      canvas.width = maxHeight;
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      dx = (maxWidth - newWidth) / 2;
      dy = (maxHeight - newHeight) / 2;
      console.log(dx, dy);
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, dx, dy, newWidth, newHeight);
      done(canvas.toDataURL());
    };
    img.src = dataURL;
  }); 
}
```

Comment: doesn't work so well if the image width is larger than the target canvas width

Answer (score 0):

For someone who search for a solution when the image is bigger that you need.

```js
      function scaleDataURL(dataURL: string, maxWidth: number, maxHeight: number) {
         return new Promise((done) => {
            var img = new Image()
            img.onload = () => {
               var scale, newWidth, newHeight, canvas, ctx
               if (img.width > maxWidth) {
                  scale = maxWidth / img.width
               } else if (img.height > maxHeight) {
                  scale = maxHeight / img.height
               } else {
                  scale = 1
               }
               newWidth = img.width * scale
               newHeight = img.height * scale
               canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
               canvas.height = newHeight
               canvas.width = newWidth
               ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
               console.log('img', 'scale', scale, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
               ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
               done(canvas.toDataURL())
            }
            img.src = dataURL
         })
      }
```

**Usage:**

```js
         scaleDataURL(base64data, 600, 200)
            .then((newBase64data) => {
               console.log(newBase64data)
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```